# What are required rights in order to make build on xcode for Apple developer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to archive the app to submit it with a "sub account" which  a client provisioned me from his Apple Developer account. When I add a developer account in Xcode from preferences, it just shows me a free developer account(probably because I have been using it as a free developer account before). And I am unable to archive. I have installed certificates and provisioning profiles also provided by the  client.

**Edit:** In iTunes connect the developer  type includes "Upload Builds" as seen in the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: For development build, free account is sufficient. But if you want to export your archive and upload to app store, agent or admin role is required.

Comment: i want to archive the build and send it appstore

Comment: So will my same account work which i have been using for free development ?

Comment: Then you need account with admin or agent rights to do it.

Comment: Sadly, no. Starting from iOS9 with xcode 7, only member with agent or admin right are able to archive and upload to app store.

Comment: this only based on my experience though, and i can't find the credible documentation for it so i might be wrong.

Comment: I have checked form iTunes Connect it mentions that a developer can upload the build. Then what could be the issue ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli   What's the exact error you're getting when trying to archive? Or is the archive function simply greyed out?

Comment: I added my account in preferences.   Then I archived the project archives and when I try to validate or submit to AppStore it asks choose account. At this place it does not show developer account..